# PhpSpreadsheet is turning number cells into decimals while reading

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I try to read a spreadsheet however when there is only numbers in a cell, it puts them as `.0` digits, ie, if the cell value is `123`, it reads it as `123.0` int. Is there a way to read them as raw string?

```
  try {
        $inputFileType = IOFactory::identify($path);

        try {
            $reader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
            $valuesSpreadsheet = $reader->load($path);

            try {
                $spreadsheetArr = $valuesSpreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
                dd($spreadsheetArr);
            }
        }
  }
```

So output is like

```
 $arr = ['A', 'B', 123.0]
```

and what I want to achieve is

```
 $arr = ['A', 'B', '123']
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this:

```
$valuesSpreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C:C')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

Comment: I just did `$a = array_map('strval', $a);` and it worked to be honest. I'll update here when I revisit that feature